# WPF : How to inherit from a base(or default) style in an ItemContainerStyle

Tags: wpf, styles, inheritance, itemcontainerstyle

I'm having trouble inheriting from a default style in an ItemContainerStyle of a TabControl.

The aim to inherit from the theme style and only changing a few properties.

If I write this XAML code, the default TabItem Style is used, but not the theme one.
Do you have any idea why?

```
<TabControl>

    <TabControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkBlue"/>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.Resources>

    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TabItem}}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>

    <TabItem Header="Tab 1"/>
    <TabItem Header="Tab 2"/>
    <TabItem Header="Tab 3"/>
    <TabItem Header="Tab 4"/>

</TabControl>
```

PS : Doing the same for a Button, in the Resources, works great. How come it does not with the TabItem Style? Something to do with the ItemContainerStyle?

PS2 : My theme style (default style) is stored in the application resources.

Thanks

**EDIT 1**

You can find the example project on my dropbox : 
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/61987557/InheritDefaultStyle.zip

Comment: I tried this code and seems working. Both button and tab item picked up the base style from App.xaml. Is there any other specific problem you facing?

Comment: Hello XAML Lover, I tried to put only this code in an application, with my default style for TabItem directly included in the App.xaml, but it still does not work. I'll upload you the source

Answer (score 0):

I guess TabItemStyle and ItemContainerStyle are two different things
**ItemContainerStyle** is applied to the container element generated for each item.
Whereas you are trying to set TabItemStyle  inside ItemContainerStyle.

Comment: Yes exactly, but that's the way to do it, isn't it? I would like to have a default style for my TabItem in a library, but the users of this library should be able to change some properties like background, without having to rewrite a whole style. Would you do it differently?

Answer (score 0):

Define a key for your TabItem's style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" x:Key="StandardTabItemControl">
...
</Style>
```

And then use this key to inherit from it:

```
<TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
   <Style TargetType="TabItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource StandardTabItemControl}">
         ...
   </Style>
</TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```